# Gamma Function Integral with discontinuity

Tags: gamma-function

$$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^{\to +\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t} \, \mathrm dt$$

For $\operatorname{Re}\left({z}\right) > 0$, and analytic continuation elsewhere, except for non positive integers.

But then, for example,

$$\Gamma\left({\frac 1 2}\right) = \int_0^{\to +\infty}t^{-1/2}e^{-t} \, \mathrm dt$$
This integrand isn't defined at $t = 0$, so what kind of integral is this? And why does the above integral make more sense than:

$$\Gamma\left({0}\right) \large{\stackrel{\text{don't}}{\normalsize=}}\normalsize \int_0^{\to +\infty}t^{-1}e^{-t} \, \mathrm dt$$

which has a similar problem at $t = 0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^a}$ is [Lebesgue Integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) on $[0,1]$ for all $a<1$ and converges as an [Improper Riemann Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) on $[0,1]$ for all $a<1$.**

To evaluate this integral, we can write for $a<1$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^1\frac{1}{x^a}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left.\left(\frac{1}{(1-a)x^{a-1}}\right)\right|_{\epsilon}^{1}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{1-a}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon^{a-1}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{1-a}
\end{align}$$

Note that for $a=1$, the integral diverges logarithmically.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between the two integrands, we have, as $a \to 0^+$,
$$
\int_a^1t^{-1/2}\: \mathrm dt=\left[2\sqrt{t}\right]_a^1=2-2\sqrt{a}\to 2<\infty
$$ whereas, as $a \to 0^+$,
$$
\int_a^1t^{-1}\: \mathrm dt=\left[\ln |t|\right]_a^1\to \infty.
$$

These are [improper integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral).

Answer (score 2):

Notice that we can define the first integral as

$$\Gamma(1/2)=\lim_{a\to0}\int_a^\infty t^{-1/2}e^{-t}dt=\sqrt\pi$$

On the other hand,

$$\Gamma(0)=\lim_{a\to0}\int_a^\infty t^{-1}e^{-t}dt\to\infty$$

As you might expect, since we have

$$\Gamma(n)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}n$$

And having $n=0$ gives $\Gamma(0)\to\infty$